PDF pages are blank after downloading the PDF using react and node js
i have a problem here in downloading PDF, i used the following snippet of code :
in the client side ( which is wrriten in react js )
const downloadReportFile = (dataUrl, filename = "default") => {
           var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = dataUrl;
  a.setAttribute("download", filename);
  a.click();
};

        const file = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
        const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
        downloadReportFile(fileURL, "AnnotatedCRF");

And in the server side, i used puppeteer to scrap a html page from rendered react component, after that i got the convert the html to PDF buffer using puppeteer and send the buffer to front end as a stream
        var pdfBuffer = await pdfGenerator
            .setHTML(pageContent)
            .setWidth(1200)
            .setHeight(1200)
            .generate();


        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/pdf');
        res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=AnnotatedCRF.pdf');
        res.setHeader('Content-Length', pdfBuffer.length);

        const stream = new Readable();
        stream.push(pdfBuffer);
        stream.push(null);
        stream.pipe(res);

That works fine and PDF generated successfully when i visit the backend endpoint from the browser directly, but when the front end uses my endpoint inside the react application, the problem occurs, all PDF pages are blank, so could anyone help me to resolve this problem ?
BTW, i want to make back end code works with the front end code without chaning anything in the front end, because i can't access front end code right now.
I tried to send the PDF buffer as arrayBuffer, and tried so many ways to fix the problem, but it didn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
